# How do use nmcli to enable dhcp for ipv4 and ipv6 on a specific interface?

Tags: networkmanager, nmcli

I recently switch an interface from not being managed by NetworkManager to being managed but it does not get an IP.

I would like to know what is the correct way to usen `nmcli` to enable dhcp on this interface? for both, ipv4/6.

PS. Obviously that I used help and google before asking here but I failed to find the magic sequence.

Answer (score 15):

Finally found it:

```
nmcli device modify eth0 ipv4.method auto
nmcli device modify eth0 ipv6.method auto

# show results
nmcli device show eth0
```

Comment: Note if the device had a static IP enabled, this will add DHCP in addition to the static IP

Answer (score 0):

your eth0 should be in "auto" by default. so DHCP is enabled by default. but since you answered your question already i would like to pint out that you can list all available configs for connections `nmcli c s eth0` and then you can modify them using `nmcli c m eth0 ipv4.method auto`. this method requires restarting of interface.